# data-toggle collapse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to hide my navbar and show it when I click on a button.
To do that, I use data-toggle.

I'm working from a template, I think that is why it doesn't work ...

Here is my code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Latest JQuery -->
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>-->


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar-header">
     <!-- Hamburger navigation -->
     <button data-target="#navbar-collapse-02" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
     </button>
</div>

<div id="navbar-collapse-02" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active propClone" id="accueil">Accueil</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="aPropos">A propos</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="devis">Devis</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="contact">Contact</li>
     </ul>
</div>  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: Only error from Jquery API (2 errors)

Comment: Can you show them to us? I think you may have a problem importing jQuery...

Comment: — simple-timeline.jquery.js:69 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'firstDate[0].slice') and Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=#undefined] in jquery.min.js:2:12788

Answer (score 0):

Remove class `navbar-collapse` from div. Simply `collapse in` class will do this. Also remove class `class="navbar-toggle"` from `button`.

```
<button data-target="#navbar-collapse-02" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>
     </button>

<div id="navbar-collapse-02" class="collapse in">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <li class="active propClone" id="accueil">Accueil</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="aPropos">A propos</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="devis">Devis</li>
         <li class="propClone" id="contact">Contact</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I copy/paste your code and actually my navbar is visible, but the hamburger button is inactive .. So the navbar is always visible, I don't understand why ^^ I'm working on it

Comment: Click the button to see what happens ?

Comment: The page is just scrolling a little bit

Comment: Nothing else in console, but why the navbar is visible by default ? I wrote aria-hidden"false" !!

Comment: Download bootstrap files locally and use from local machine rather referencing online.

Comment: My precedent code (two days ago) works, but I don't know why .. So I don't think it's a problem from Bootstrap ^^

Comment: This code is working for me. I have referenced files locally.

Comment: Ok, i'll try as soon as possible :)

Comment: Could you show me how to kink EVERY JS files please ? Because the folder JS contains a lot of file ^^

Comment: Add three files first jquery file than bootstrap.js and than bootstrap.css

Comment: All this files must be in <head></head> ?

Comment: Yes in head or at end of document. try both one by one

Comment: My links are bad .. I have 5 errors : Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (x3) and in jquery.min.js there is an unrecognized expression : [href=#undefinied]

Comment: In all Bootstrap files I just linked .min.js ans .min.css

Comment: Try the files without min.

Comment: Just to check comment the bootstrap.js

Answer (score 0):

Please highlight in your question what does not work?
Check if you have not accidentally assigned same id to other block and expecting the change here.

I think you should remove "navbar-collapse" from div with id id="navbar-collapse-02"

Refer:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Comment: I don't have the same id. And i did what Leopard told me ^^